# Different way to do a LIKE WHERE condition?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a query which works fine:

```
  SELECT  
         month_date= month(SendTime) ,year_date =year(sendtime) ,MessageType
          ,COUNT(MessageType) AS MESSAGE_COUNT
  FROM Message
  WHERE year(SendTime)= 2014
      and messagetype NOT LIKE '%test%' 
      and messagetype NOT LIKE '%ANOTHER THING%' 
      and messagetype NOT LIKE '%STUFF%' 
  GROUP BY month(SendTime),year(sendtime), MessageType
```

What I notice is with having `LIKE` conditions it has made the 
the elapse time slower.

With the above query it runs at elapsed time .550, without them .154.

Is there a different way I can be able to cut this time and make query faster?

No messagetype is not index and i am not allow to change it.

Comment: Even if you had an index, it would be of little use - wild card searches like yours can't use them. If you had ... NOT LIKE 'test%', then an index would be beneficial. And of course your query is going to be slower when you add conditions (i.e. NOT LIKE...). Why does this surprise you?

Comment: Are you not allowed to add indexes or not allowed to change the query?

Comment: How many rows in this table?  Do you have a numeric key column?  Are there *any* indexes?  What about statistics?

Comment: Please add in the question the `CREATE TABLE` script.

Comment: Your second AND messagetype NOT LIKE '%test1%' is superfluous - it will be covered by your first NOT LIKE criterion.

Comment: @maxvernon its a huge table 200k,

Comment: @ypercube im not allowed to add indexes ,I can change query

Comment: 200k is **not** "huge". You've been asked to provide a `SHOW CREATE TABLE\G` - voting to close unless further information is forthcoming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have been asked to provide further information - you have not yet done so.

Comment: @Vérace The %test1% is likely because the user scrubbed the query before putting it here. I don't think you can make the assumption it is superfluous. Also while it's nice to get a table script and sample data I'm not sure it's 100% needed here.

Answer (score 5):

Two things you can do:

- Use `SendTime >= '20140101' AND SendTime < '20150101'` instead of the `year(SendTime)= 2014`. This makes the condition sargable and indexes can be used.
- Add a composite index on `(SendTime, MessageType)` so the query does not have to do a full table scan but only a (partial) index scan.

The query rewritten:

```
SELECT  
    month_date = month(SendTime),
    year_date = year(SendTime),
    MessageType,
    message_count = COUNT(MessageType) 
FROM Message
WHERE SendTime >= '20140101' AND SendTime < '20150101'
  AND MessageType NOT LIKE '%test%' 
  AND MessageType NOT LIKE '%ANOTHER THING%' 
  AND messagetype NOT LIKE '%STUFF%' 
GROUP BY year(SendTime), month(SendTime), MessageType ;
```

---

Another option would be to add computed columns on `year(SendTime)` and `month(SendTime)` and an index on `year(SendTime), month(SendTime), MessageType` - and keep the original query!

Answer (score 3):

You could try an indexed view.  I know you said you couldn't add an index to the table but this would be creating a view and then indexing it.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Message
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT  
        month_date= month(SendTime) ,year_date =year(sendtime) ,MessageType,
        COUNT_BIG(*) AS MESSAGE_COUNT
      FROM dbo.Message
      where year(SendTime)= 2014
      and messagetype NOT LIKE '%test%' 
      and messagetype NOT LIKE '%ANOTHER THING%' 
      and messagetype NOT LIKE '%STUFF%' 
      group by month(SendTime),year(sendtime), MessageType
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_vw_Message ON 
    vw_Message(month_date, year_date, MessageType)
```

Warnings:

- By schemabinding a view on the table you will only be able to modify the table structure if you drop the view, make the change, and then re-create the view.
- If MessageType is larger than 892 characters (assuming a varchar not an nvarchar) then you will get the following warning:
  **Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'ix_vw_Message' has maximum length of 2008 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.**
  In this case any insert on the table that makes `MessageType` to large will cause the insert to fail.

On an up note your query will be blindingly fast :)

```
SELECT * FROM vw_Message
```